# open excel file as readonly from process start

Tags: c#, .net, excel-interop

I have to open an excel application using the Process.Start method. Current code is below.

```
startInfo.FileName = "EXCEL.EXE";            
startInfo.Arguments = "\"C:\\Shared\\Some Directory\\File Name 2016.xlsm";
var res = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

I only need read access to the file. However if another user has the file open a window prompt pops up asking if I would like to open the file in read only mode. Is there anyway using the Process.Start method to specify that the file only needs to be opened as read only?

I have read about using verbs however think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Documentation link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Excel-321cf55a-ace4-40b3-9082-53bd4bc10725)

Just use `/r` key:

```
startInfo.FileName = "EXCEL.EXE";            
startInfo.Arguments = "/r \"C:\\Shared\\Some Directory\\File Name 2016.xlsm\"";
var res = Process.Start(startInfo);
```