# ProcessStartInfo - Verb not working

Tags: c#, processstartinfo

I used

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(filepath);

if (File.Exists(filepath))
{
    var i = 0;
    foreach (String verb in startInfo.Verbs)
    {
        // Display the possible verbs.
        Console.WriteLine("  {0}. {1}", i.ToString(), verb);
        i++;
    }
}
```

To find the verbs available for the file selected, then tried..

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(filepath);
psi.Verb = "OpenAsReadOnly";
Process wordProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
```

and the file(excel) I am trying to open is not opening in readonly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open excel file as readonly from process start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409017/open-excel-file-as-readonly-from-process-start)

Comment: The verb uses the /h option, documented as "opens a read-only copy of a document that is stored on a Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services site"... "If the document is checked out to you, the /h switch has no effect. Word opens the file so that you can edit it."

Comment: I viewed the link above, have it working but sometimes it opens in readonly and some open in protected view

Comment: startInfo.FileName = "EXCEL.EXE";
                    startInfo.Arguments = "/r \"" + filepath;
                    var res = Process.Start(startInfo);